# fading out to 50% does not work

Tags: jquery

I need your help. I looked in all tutorials but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I want the blue square to be faded out to 50% opacity. I tried already with fadeTo but for whatever resons it did not work. What do I need to do. Where is my mistake? Thank you so much!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#divA").mouseover(function(){$("#divB").fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function());
   $("#divA").mouseout(function(){$("#divB").fadeTo('slow', 1, function());
  });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  #divA { background:red; width:25px; height:25px; margin:50px }
  #divB { background:blue; width:200px; height:200px }
</style>
</head>
<body>
Hover over the red square to fadeout the blue one to 50% opacity.<br>
The blue square fades back in when your cursor leaves the red one.
<div id="divA"></div>
<div id="divB"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You lack a closing bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few syntax errors in the javascript.  It was missing closing braces and closing parens.  Also there was no need for the empty callback, which was missing opening and closing braces.

Try:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#divA").mouseover(function(){
          $("#divB").fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
      });

      $("#divA").mouseout(function(){
          $("#divB").fadeTo('slow', 1);
      });
  });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XnBQ6/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't closing your functions.

```
$("#divA").mouseover(function(){
  $("#divB").fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
```

Should be:

```
$("#divA").mouseover(function(){
  $("#divB").fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
});
```